# SQLite random() rows but 1 of them must have a specific value?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So, I am developing a kind of Quiz game, the game will have a question on the screen and below 4 buttons, which will be filled with 1 right answer and 3 wrong answers. Simple right? I'm trying to use the following rawQuery() to load 4 answers, all of them must be random, except the right answer that has to appear.

**SQLite:**

```
myCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QuestionID = 3 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4", null);
```

So, QuestionID is the field that is specifying which question is being displayed to load the proper answers. I'll need to have a lot of answers so that the player can't memorise them. Is something like this pseudo-code possible?

```
myCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QuestionID = 3 ORDER BY RANDOM('WHERE RightWrong = 1 LIMIT 1') LIMIT 4", null);
```

RightWrong is the field that tells if it's the right answer or not (inside the DB), it's an INT, if it is set to 1 then it is the correct answer.

I'm using SQLiteAssetHelper with SQLite DB Browser.

Comment: would be easier to start by selecting the correct answer, then select 3 random wrong answers, then shuffle them together.

Comment: @njzk2 That's what I will do if i can't resolve things this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably try a query along the lines of the following join.

```
myCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Answers
    WHERE QuestionID = 3 AND RightWrong = 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3)
    UNION SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QuestionID = 3 AND
    RightWrong = 1 LIMIT 1)) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4", null)
```

A couple things to note, first this is not a tested query and I'm not 100% sure the SQL syntax is correct but it should help you get the idea of what I mean. Also I believe this will always put the correct answer as the last value returned and you will need to randomize where this is at a later point in your code. I hope this helps.

--EDIT--
Fixed the query so it is one that actually works

Comment: Ok, I'll try it Teeto, give me a sec.

Comment: Well, that syntax doesn't work, I'm gonna do some research after a little break.

Comment: Yeah, it's been a while since I've written SQL so I apologize for the bad syntax. I'll see if I can fix it in a bit.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it. `JOIN` needed to be `UNION`.

Comment: Ok, I got it man, if you want, change you answer to: `myCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QuestionID = 3 AND RightWrong = 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3) UNION SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QuestionID = 3 AND RightWrong = 1 LIMIT 1)) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4", null)` I'll mark it as accepted :) Thank you very much for the tip :) Oh btw, here's how this works, when you use union you pretty much combine the 2 statements into one, so you can only user `LIMIT and ORDER BY` at the end to filter the combined results, so you use sub-queries :)

Comment: It's fixed. Happy I could help. It's odd that my first fixed worked in a syntax checker when you can only use `limit` and `order by` once though... Oh well. It's working and that's what matters